# Spring Angular authentication fail

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security

My basic auth class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthConfiguration
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().cors().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
            "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "X-XSS-Protection", "X-Content-Type-Options"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
}
```

my test rest controller is:

```
@Api(value="BMT test", description="BMT test system")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bmt/api/v1")
public class TestRestController {

@CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)
@GetMapping("/test/get")
public String getTest() {
    return "test";
}

@CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)
@PostMapping ("/test/post")
public String getTest2(String param) {
    return "test";
}

}
```

on angular site I have :

```
   public logUser(userLogin: string, password: string): any {
    const token = this.createBasicAuthToken('user', 'user')
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': token
        })
    };
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/bmt/api/v1/test/post`,{},
        httpOptions).subscribe(
        data => console.log('success', data),
        error => console.log('oops', error)
    );


}

public createBasicAuthToken(userLogin: String, password: String): string {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(userLogin + ':' + password);
}
```

But IDK why I can go and connect by postman to get method, but to get method I can from the same controller. But if I try to connect to get by angular I cannot anyway. I have no idea.

I need spring boot / angular 5,6,7 ( I can easy update) authentication system, but whatever I try I fail. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the user and the password to the `logUser` Method without doing nothing with it.

If you want to use basic auth in your request you have to set the `Authorization` in your request header. But first you have to create the basic auth token form user and password.

> The username and password are combined with a single colon (:). This means that the username itself cannot contain a colon.
>   The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence. The character set to use for this encoding is by default unspecified, as long as it is compatible with US-ASCII, but the server may suggest use of UTF-8 by sending the charset parameter.[7]
>   The resulting string is encoded using a variant of Base64.
>   The authorization method and a space (e.g. "Basic ") is then prepended to the encoded string. [see on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Something like: `token = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(userLogin+':'+password)`;

Try this:

```
public logUser(userLogin: string, password: string): any {
  const token = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(userLogin+':'+password)`
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': token
    })
  };
return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/bmt/api/v1/test/post`,
    {}, httpOptions).subscribe(
    data => console.log('success', data),
    error => console.log('oops', error)
);
```

And remenber to pass in the `httpOptions` in your request.

Comment: my fault- I deleted call of method - I made it before- I have still 401 :/

Comment: If you check the devTool network request, is the authorization set correctly in the header?

Comment: I updated question. We send "Basic SOMETHINGENCODED" as header

I have problem that when I use postman I have also problem with POST mapping. I think here is smth wrong with Spring also

Comment: Generally you should use a response of type `ResponseEntity` in your API endpoints. And the body of the request can be achieved over `@RequestBody`. For instance in the post endpoint 

`public ResponseEntity<String> getTest2(@RequestBody String(or some other type) param) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok("test");
}`

Comment: .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()); when I will remove it start to works :/ Damn Where to find tutorial angular + spring boot authentication by token :P